# ggplot2: Some geom_point shape result in strange color

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I am facing a rather weird problem. I want the `geom_point`to have the shape `|`. Doing so gives me a plot with some discolouration. There seems to be some green and yellow color although I set colors to black. I thought I was wrong but saving the plot and zooming in confirmed my feeling.

I am doing this

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species)) +
  geom_point(shape= 124, size= 20, col= "black")
```

What I get is this (I zoomed in to clarify the problem):

[image: plot]

You may have to click on the image to see what I mean. Interestingly, this does not happen if I use `shape= 1`:

[image: okay]

Comment: Isn't this just an artefact of the image itself rather than anything to do with ggplot? If you save the ggplot in a vector format such as pdf, doesn't this just disappear?

Comment: @AllanCameron This problem appears even before I save the plot. I can see it in the R Studio plot panel. But the strange thing is: Once I export it as a pdf the problem disappears. Can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: That's an optical effect and called chromatic aberration. You probably don't see it with the other shapes because the lines are too thin to create contrast. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_aberration

Comment: I was wrong ! See @AllanCameron's reply below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is simply imaging artefact rather than anything to do with ggplot as such. If you save the plot in vector format like pdf and zoom way in, the chromatic fringes aren't "really" there:

[image]

Comment: It's not really an image artefact, it's an optical effect (chromatic aberration.)

Comment: @Tjebo this isn't chromatic aberration (I know you are an Ophthalmologist, but let me explain). If you zoom into the image posted by the OP you can clearly see the color fringes getting bigger, and sample the pixels objectively to see that they are genuinely there. If this were an image produced by a lens, you could say it was chromatic aberration. I can see colour fringes on pure black against pure white on my monitor which _are_ due to chromatic aberration, but chromatic aberration will not scale up if you zoom in (unless the image was recorded via a lens).

Comment: You are right! Very curious, especially as those pixels actually follow the side of 'normal' chromatic aberration...

Comment: Exactly my thoughts, @Tjebo. I was reluctant to post an answer because I can't explain why this would happen.

Answer (score 1):

[In addition to user Allan Camerons answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60829948/7941188), I don't think this is an image artefact (nor chromatic aberration :). This seems to be intended and part of anti-aliasing, called [subpixel rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering).

Related: [See also this thread](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/930/why-does-anti-aliasing-in-black-characters-use-colors-other-than-gray-scale) .

Possibly, it may be a sort of convention to display black with red pixels shown left, and blue pixels shown to the right (??), and therefore subpixel rendering would show those colors to each side.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the correct explanation.